# Cómo cambiar la posición de un elemento y ubicarlo en la posición que se requiera

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando poner el circulo azul en el medio de los otros dos colores, pero me lo ubica en la última posición, intenté hacer el *insertBefore* a la etiqueta amarilla pero el circulo azúl no aparece

```js
var blue = document.querySelector(".blue");

document.querySelector(".colors").insertBefore(blue, null);
```

```css
.colors{
display: flex;
}
.colors > span{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin: 5px;
border-radius: 50%;
display: blocK;
}
.yellow{
background-color: #ffff00;
}
.blue{
background-color: #0000ff;
}
.red{
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">

<span class="blue"></span>

<span class="yellow"></span>


<span class="red"></span>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp), *El método `insertBefore()` inserta un nodo hijo antes de un hijo existente*.

Si dejas el segundo parámetro de `insertBefore()` en `null` te lleva el nodo a la posición final.

En su lugar debes obtener **el elemento anterior a la posición que necesitas** y luego hacer el movimiento. En tu caso, debes obtener el último elemento hijo del contenedor `colors`.

```js
//Obtener el elemento a mover
var blue = document.querySelector(".blue");
//Obtener el último elemento hijo del contenedor colors
var last = document.querySelector(".colors").lastElementChild;
//Realizar el movimiento antes del último elemento hijo
document.querySelector(".colors").insertBefore(blue, last);
```

```css
.colors {
  display: flex;
}

.colors>span {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: blocK;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
  <span class="blue"></span>
  <span class="yellow"></span>
  <span class="red"></span>
</div>
```